# Display even numbers between 0 - 100 in a table, including 0 with php

Tags: php, html, for-loop, html-table, numbers

I would like to display the numbers between 0 and 100 (including 0) in a column.

[image: How the table should look like]

This is the code that I have right now...

```
<?php

echo "<table border=1><tr><td>";
for ($_getal = 0; $_getal < 100; $_getal++) {

    if ($_getal % 2 == 0) {
        echo "$_getal<br>";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: @evilrabbit is it need to show in singe row or multiple row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
echo "<table border=1 style='width:20%;border: 2px solid #101216;border-collapse: collapse;'>";
    $temp = 0;
    for ($_getal = 0; $_getal < 100; $_getal++) 
    {
        if($temp == 0 && $_getal % 2 == 0)
        {
            echo "<td style='text-align:center;'>";
        }
        if ($_getal % 2 == 0) 
        {
            echo "$_getal<br>";
            $temp++;
        }
        if($temp == 5 && $_getal % 2 == 0)
        {
            $temp = 0;
             echo "</td>";
        }
    }
echo "</table>";

?>
```

Comment: Out of all the answers, this one fits best!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
echo '<table border="1">';
for ($_getal = 0; $_getal < 100; $_getal++) {
    echo "<tr><td>$_getal</td></tr>";
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done some modification in your code.

```
<?php
echo "<table border=1>";
    $temp = 0;
    for ($_getal = 0; $_getal < 100; $_getal++) 
    {
        if($temp == 0 && $_getal % 2 == 0)
        {
            echo "<th>";
        }
        if ($_getal % 2 == 0) 
        {
            echo "$_getal<br>";
            $temp++;
        }
        if($temp == 5 && $_getal % 2 == 0)
        {
            $temp = 0;
             echo "</th>";
        }
    }

?>
```

**OUTPUT**:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo '<table border="1">';
for ($_getal = 0; $_getal < 100; $_getal+=2) {
    echo "<tr><td>$_getal</td></tr>";
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should decide how many rows you want (in your example you have 5).

The difference between the first number of the first column (0) and first number of the second column (10) is the amount of rows (5) times 2

Your for loop goes through every number, however: it's more memory efficient if you just do `$_getal+=2`

```
<?php
$_maxNumber = 100;
$_numberStep = 2;
$_numberOfRows = 5;

echo '<table border=1><tr>';

for ($_startGetal = 0; $_startGetal < $_maxNumber; $_startGetal += $_numberStep * $_numberOfRows) {
    echo '<td>';

    for ($_getal = $_startGetal; $_getal < $_startGetal + $_numberStep * $_numberOfRows; $_getal += $_numberStep) {
        echo "$_getal<br>";
    }

    echo '</td>';
}

echo '</tr></table>';
?>
```

I added 2 as a variable, so you could do steps of any number.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing it.

I create an array from 0-8 with range, this is the leftmost numbers in the table.
Then i loop them and I loop the "tens" in the for loop.
I place tens and single digits next to eachother and multiply with 1 to make it an integer (removes leading zeros).

```
$numb = range(0,8, 2);

echo "<table border=1>";
foreach($numb as $val){
    echo "<tr>";
    for($tens=0;$tens<=9; $tens++){
        echo "<td>" . ($tens.$val)*1 . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>";
```

If you change the for loop to `for($tens=0;$tens<=19; $tens++){` it will count to 198 instead